# xrdp disconnects immediately after connection from Windows10/Centos to Centos7

Tags: centos, windows, xrdp

This is my xrdp config:

```
[Globals]
ini_version=1
fork=true
port=3389
use_vsock=false
tcp_nodelay=true
tcp_keepalive=true
security_layer=negotiate
crypt_level=high
certificate=
key_file=
ssl_protocols=TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3
autorun=
allow_channels=true
allow_multimon=true
bitmap_cache=true
bitmap_compression=true
bulk_compression=true
max_bpp=128
use_compression=yes
new_cursors=true
use_fastpath=both
blue=009cb5
grey=dedede
ls_top_window_bg_color=009cb5
ls_width=350
ls_height=430
ls_bg_color=dedede
ls_logo_filename=
ls_logo_x_pos=55
ls_logo_y_pos=50
ls_label_x_pos=30
ls_label_width=65
ls_input_x_pos=110
ls_input_width=210
ls_input_y_pos=220
ls_btn_ok_x_pos=142
ls_btn_ok_y_pos=370
ls_btn_ok_width=85
ls_btn_ok_height=30
ls_btn_cancel_x_pos=237
ls_btn_cancel_y_pos=370
ls_btn_cancel_width=85
ls_btn_cancel_height=30
[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=true
SyslogLevel=DEBUG
[Channels]
rdpdr=true
rdpsnd=true
drdynvc=true
cliprdr=true
rail=true
xrdpvr=true
tcutils=true
[Xvnc]
name=Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
[Xorg]
name=Xorg
lib=libxup.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
code=20
```

I am trying to connect with mstsc to this machine (this is after fresh pc restart, noone has logged in):

[image]

while in this login box, no disconnect happens:

[image]

after I put there correct login/password, I get black screen first and then mstsc window closes. I tried to connect from KDE remote connection application, but it also failed same way. xrdp.log doesn't seem to contain anything interesting:

```
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
[20190606-04:14:36] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sending login info to session manager, please wait...
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] return value from xrdp_mm_connect 0
[20190606-04:14:36] [INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC started connecting
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC connecting to 127.0.0.1 5910
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC tcp connected
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC security level is 2 (1 = none, 2 = standard)
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC password ok
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending share flag
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC receiving server init
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC receiving pixel format
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC receiving name length
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC receiving name
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending pixel format
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending encodings
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending framebuffer update request
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC sending cursor
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: VNC connection complete, connected ok
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_wm_log_msg: connected ok
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_connect_chansrv: chansrv connect successful
[20190606-04:14:36] [DEBUG] Closed socket 18 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:47744)
[20190606-04:14:37] [DEBUG] Closed socket 20 (AF_UNIX)
[20190606-04:14:37] [DEBUG] Closed socket 12 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3389)
[20190606-04:14:37] [DEBUG] xrdp_mm_module_cleanup
[20190606-04:14:37] [DEBUG] VNC mod_exit
[20190606-04:14:37] [DEBUG] Closed socket 19 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:40224)
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: After I Remote from Windows 10 to xrdp Fedora OS, it would exit my RDC session on Windows, after banging my head on the wall, I tried on logging out of my linux user then tried logging in again with mstsc/remote session

Comment: Just log out the same user from the console and that's it :) Perhaps

Comment: @InOrder said the answer that was happing with me. You cannot log in the same user, if it is already logged.

Comment: LOG OUT from the machine you want to connect to remotely! That did it for me.

Comment: I had this issue and thanks to @InOrder , after log-out from the user in the Ubuntu machine I was able to connect with RDP.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved the issue myself, hopefully someone else will find it usefull. I took a look at ~/.xsession-errors, it contained:

```
(imsettings-check:16467): IMSettings-WARNING **: 04:42:56.491: Could not connect: Connection refused

(imsettings-check:16467): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 04:42:56.491: g_dbus_proxy_call_sync_internal: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_PROXY (proxy)' failed
GLib-GIO-Message: 04:42:56.807: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.

** (process:16260): WARNING **: 04:42:56.824: Could not make bus activated clients aware of XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME environment variable: Could not connect: Connection refused
```

and then I've googled a rootcause, miniconda installation has broken PATH in .bashrc file, I have **removed** this line and it has fixed it:

```
    export PATH="/home/stiv/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

**UPDATE:** Later I've found [x2go](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/x2go-server-ubuntu-14-04/), which works way more reliable and faster then XRDP.

Comment: Can you add a link for the source you found via google that pointed you in the right direction?

Comment: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1206

Comment: Works for me too! I only have the first two lines of error (could not connect & g_dbus_proxy error), but it seems to also be bashrc/zshrc problem. I temporarily remove the .bashrc and .zshrc and it works!

Comment: So this was an issue with your $PATH environment variable being hosed up somehow? I'm facing a similar issue, where the windows client will connect but then immediately disconnect. The logs show similar output. I don't have anaconda installed though, just regular python. But I am adjusting the PATH environment variable.

Comment: hi I have the same problem but I can;t find a solution. Where is the ~/.xsession-errors file? Is it in the home directory? It doesn't exist in my computer. I need to use Windows 10 Remote Desktop as the connecting client, so I've used xrdp. If I install x2go do I need a dedicated x2go client or can I still use windows remote desktop to connect? I used the instructions here to install xrdp: https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-centos-8/

Comment: @stiv nevermind, the issue was this: https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1432, user should be logged out on CentOS machine. Just leaving the comment here in case someone finds it useful

Comment: This did not apply to my failure case since I am not using miniconda3

Answer (score 31):

Try this:

Stop xrdp with
`sudo service xrdp stop`

Edit the xrdp start script:
`sudo nano /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh`

In this file, replace the lines

```
test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
```

with
`startxfce4`

(You can comment out lines by adding `#` at the start)

Restart xrdp with
`sudo service xrdp start`

Select Xrdp as the session, and log in.

Comment: I don have a Xrdp option as session, I only have these: Xorg, Xvnc, vnc-any, neutrinordp-any

Comment: Could you post what type of object is `startxfce4`? You could enter at the command line `type startxfce4`. Strangely, I am not finding it.

Comment: ```$ type startxfce4
startxfce4 is /usr/bin/startxfce4```
I'm not sure which package exactly installed xfce4 - probably desktop-base?
```$ apt-cache rdepends xfce4
xfce4
Reverse Depends:
 |desktop-base
  xfwm4```

Comment: Sorted it for me, thanks!

Comment: If more than 1 user needs to simultaneously login remotely with the same credentials this solution freezes the remote desktop for everyone forcing you to reboot to solve the problem

Comment: this work fr me. thanks

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: For `gnome` users, the magic to be added (instead of `test -x... ) is `exec gnome-session`

Answer (score 5):

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt install xrdp`
3. `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core`
4. `sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp`
5. `nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/02-allow-colord.conf`
6. Copy the polkit below to `02-allow-colord.conf`

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
if ((action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device" || action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile" || action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device" || action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile" || action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device" || action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile") && subject.isInGroup("{group}"))
{
return polkit.Result.YES;
}
});
```

7. `sudo ufw allow 3389/tcp`
8. `sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart`
9. `sudo systemctl status xrdp`
10. `sudo systemctl enable xrdp`
11. Log out of your session.
12. Try with RDP

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu. Thank you. What does the polkit do?

Comment: Please make sure you have typed " and not the curly “ ” when pasting into this forum

Comment: This fixed connection issues in between Remmina (Ubuntu 20.04) and  Ubuntu 21.04 x64 for Raspberry 4.

Answer (score 4):

The user account you are trying this with, are they a member of the `sudo` or `wheel` groups?  With Kali 2020 edition, any user that is apart of `sudo` will disconnect immediately, I had to kill all processes of that user ( `pkill -u <username>` ) and then delete the user account and recreate it.  I am still tracking down the exact reason why this is occurring when I have time.  But thought I share my experience.

Comment: Notice that this question focuses on a connection between Windows and CentOS....

Comment: I had this similar issue when going to Ubuntu. Had to log off of the sudo user in order to log in, otherwise the RDP session closed immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You must do following additional actions:

To Configure Xrdp, first add

```
exec gnome-session
```

to the end of the configuration file

```
/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini
```

Or use following command to add “exec gnome-session” to the end of the “/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini” configuration file

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "exec gnome-session" >> /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini'
```

Restart xrdp to load the new configuration

```
sudo systemctl restart xrdp
```

Reference:
[How to: Install Xrdp (Remote Desktop) on CentOS 8 – (How to: Use Windows to remote control CentOS 8)](https://dannyda.com/2020/02/09/how-to-install-xrdp-remote-desktop-on-centos-8-how-to-use-windows-to-remote-control-centos-8/?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=7a82a89d62a36917cc984d62bc19b24d4d7de286-1619776226-0-AYZAmlw4_8CeSF4u3Nn94e-fq7XOgXK8_qAKB3wUU3r5ovSxVIhLOfLlS_vxODL5WcDdcFnqB0fKpzOI5l4eju7mGchEIPNLyMMVJWxKe1INI1KKJQ0p9vtpSUMqZOyK5vEqozcF7eeb91h1r6_ThABvaSufa_CJEqGWhks4ZZMvmK8FdAIDeRfrANdu2OpM0AmbZG0R_qafZT7JwclLrEk4JcQ3bJk3jgJSzeauMWJc_YuGTVWK9mpKkx3TLkM6eq9-5ye_gVV42DrbCzWY-D27WmNxasD_GFdLxvY94s56_wcuk19SubxGsb2JUgtdOfL4Mi-ivHXd1lKQD3IejtF7EcJ5URIcWODvKWrEbow7P7bBUQ1hDSw6mfhI3f8_wqvvjnCCqC9HSVRD4tZF9N0dOyaYgSDfKRkOPtl1dC7I6dCUuqdO2qJQOYfMvwcT-6n7nmBVKWOzQlK1-38r2fla6zxfxNOMk5FNIGUFRMaW3-esAspm9wVEnF7Z0n6wC4BOnrh6XArPyGvKkUJyKTEDGalORFEJZpdcuQqFEM_ECZy9PgXuHRE6EXdCFkO1vfLVdcCMm0tql91lsyNTyqqSEmd1PZKNt2rpwCyrBO8mkYYfmNqhAuLsICr1jaZwuECtsKujc4LVpefOnG0ha3NhrYlIqCW_61F_RW2NoB1RNyx7mJFo5eICzMGNpAvL_Npc8T1OwMKkInYgHRzDoP9a4mVR9pIc2nsMzcN9CjuhSxKZKoGP0Se8SqxQTpTijQ)

Comment: I followed your guide (apart from the firewall stuff that I didn't need to do) and it worked perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue trying to connect to a work machine running xrdp on red hat enterprise Linux 7. I had installed miniconda and datalad in its base environment in my home folder on the remote machine and that broke windows remote desktop. The solution was surprisingly simple. I uninstalled datalad and reinstalled it in a new environment via SSH. I was then able to reconnect to the machine via windows remote desktop without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent many days  over the past few years with the intermittent problems of accessing a Linux server from a Windows 10 PC. Different approaches to Server xrdp.ini modifications appear to straighten out the issue, but non permanently. After failing with fresh RHEL8 and Centos8 installs, all failing with a PC RDP logon, I observed the following common error. After a fail from the PC, the error, observed from a "semi" successful re-logon from the same PC was observable in `systemctl status xrdp` which presents the litany of the failed items.
However, when observed directly on the server itself using a screen, keyboard and mouse( I have the Dell R430 in next to me), the `systemctl status xrdp`, appears clean with no problems.
Each fresh logon to RDP, with Xvnc, apparently launches a separate rdp session/process.
The conclusion I have reached is that the problem is focused on the PC and somehow a SSL failure. It is persistent on the PC UNTIL IT IS rebooted.
The server does not require a restart.
Of course, REBOOTING the PC is impractical, but it is repeatedly successful.

Answer (score 0):

I troubleshooted this too, and, it seems that just installing the xrdp package on it's own is not enough, because (1) dependent packages will not get installed, (2) startwm.sh issues. I didn't arrive at a perfect solution. I notice one of the other answers is using xfce4 which I would like to use to. In the end, I defaulted to something more lightweight, i.e. icewm, i.e.

```bsh
sudo yum update
sudo yum install xrdp
sudo yum install tigervnc-server
sudo yum install xterm
sudo yum install icewm
sudo vi /usr/libexec/xrdp/startwm.sh
```

And, effectively, my `startwm.sh` script has the following at the top, i.e. I've circumvented or replaced the default behavior:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -xe
/bin/xterm &
exec /bin/icewm
```