# xrdp disconnects after logging into CentOS 7 machine

Tags: centos, remote-desktop, xrdp, rdp

CentOS 7 image was installed with Gnome desktop to local server (on same LAN as the Windows computer I used to access it).

Neither machine uses a VPN.

etc/services says that port 3389 is being used for ms wbt server, which I assume is correct.

The Firewall Configuration marks 3389 as a public port with the TCP protocol.

xrdp was installed to CentOS server using this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iFslyE_oaXc

When I attempt to make the connection from Remote Desktop Connection on my Windows machine to my remote CentOS desktop, I'm opened up a a window that says this:

[image]

When I click "ok" it sends me to the login screen for xrdp (session set to Xvnc). But when I try to log in, it just closes out of everything and shows the default Remote Desktop Connection menu.

I want to reiterate that xrdp is indeed active on my system (I checked the status to make sure it's running on port 3389/tcp too). Everything is up to date and all dependencies are installed as per the above video.

There's a similar post here ([xrdp disconnects immediately after connection from Windows10/Centos to Centos7](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523152/xrdp-disconnects-immediately-after-connection-from-windows10-centos-to-centos7)) but I don't seem to have a startwm.sh file nor do I have a .xsession-errors file anywhere in my system. All of the other solutions listed didn't do anything either.

There are a few other similar posts but they didn't get any responses that worked for my system.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.