# authentication is required to create a color profile on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, authentication

I upgrade Ubuntu version from **18.04** to **20.04**

But when update is complete i found a issues again and again on screen.
Here is the screenshot in given below:

[image]

How to fix these issues. I entered my password but it still showing after entering password then after few times it comes again.

Need to fix it asap! Is anyone getting this error?

Comment: please try to login with the CLI first. press `ctrl+alt+f1` and try to login your user.is it working ?

Comment: not working i tried with `ctrl+alt+f1` but still got these issues

Comment: I got the exact same issue and found solution here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496519/443634

Comment: I got the exact same issue and found solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496519/443634

Comment: @WesB. I applied this solutions and it fixed but now power not working restart not working what can i do now?

Comment: Fixed it by this solutions: [click here to view solutions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496519/365959)

Answer (score 4):

A working solution can be found [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12043). All the credits for this answer goes to [Griffon](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?author=1) (Thanks!).

Create this file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/45-allow-colord.pkla`.
(I did as root, file-mode should be 644)

**45-allow-colord.pkla**

```
[Allow Colord all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
```

and check for potential errors in `/var/crash/`. If there are any, remove all the files `sudo rm /var/crash/*`

Check with remote connection if the problem is solved.

Comment: I got this working.  I had to reboot before it worked. It is a bit slow.  I tried using Griffon's full script, not sure if that helped or not.  The main slowness is when it's fading out/in the screen for the authentication prompts.  Other stuff is fast enough.  Note this is on a local LAN, so it might be much slower over the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

First login with the CLI,
press `ctrl+alt+f1` or `f2` then login with your user then try below steps,

found this bug here:

```
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1149893
```

Specifically you have to place .rule file here,

```
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/
```

(add a filename and just give the .rules extension)

give below  rules:

```
polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
   if ((action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-profile" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-profile" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device" ||
        action.id == "org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile") &&
       subject.isInGroup("username")) {
      return polkit.Result.YES;
   }
});
```

Then you have to Replace the word "username" with your user's group.

Comment: is this the any name with `.rules` extensions. I create `rule.rules` then paste these code on there then save it

Comment: this problem is not fixed yet, anyone please check this one